# Are tr1 headers available for gcc v3.4.6?

Tags: c++, g++, header, tr1

Are tr1 headers available for g++ v3.4.6?  If so, how can I locate them at compile time.

The following is failing to compile:

```
#include <tr1/memory>
```

With the following error:

```
myModule.h:20:24: tr1/memory: No such file or directory
```

Do I need to move to a later compiler or do I have the headers somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, Boost provides a [TR1 implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html) too.